# What is best way to host Mobile application server code (Node.js) in AWS

Tags: node.js, server, backend

I want deplay a node.j server code for mobile application. What is the best way to to that restfull  or ec2. how to do that in aws.

Answer (score 0):

these are help link you can read these  and deployed it on aws and enjoy it!!!

https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-creating-and-managing-a-node-js-server-on-aws-part-1-d67367ac5171

https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-nodejs-web-app/

https://medium.com/@nishankjaintdk/setting-up-a-node-js-app-on-a-linux-ami-on-an-aws-ec2-instance-with-nginx-59cbc1bcc68c

Comment: Those for Web Applications, I need this for Only api services for mobile app, services should be in https